# Query last commit to a git repo without cloning

Tags: git

Suppose I wish to clone a large git repo from a URL, if and only if a commit was made to master within the last `n` (say 24) hours. I don't want to clone it, because that's rather time-consuming for such a large repo, nor do I wish to clone it once and then check e.g. git status periodically.

I want to be able to tell when the last commit was made prior to cloning. Is there a way of doing this in git? If not, what are my options? I know I can get the hash of the last commit via `git ls-remote`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option could be to go ahead and clone the repo, but only with a depth of 1. This should make for a very fast download.

Then, you could check the tip of master's timestamp.

Example:

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/jquery/jquery.git jquery
```

See [this](https://www.perforce.com/blog/141218/git-beyond-basics-using-shallow-clones) article for more information.

> Git supports the notion of a “shallow clone”, which is a more
>   succinctly meaningful way of describing a local repository with
>   history truncated to a particular depth during the clone operation. By
>   providing an argument of --depth 1 to the clone command, the process
>   will copy only the latest revision of everything in the repository.

--

Another option, if your target repo is on GitHub, would be to use GitHub's REST API like this:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha
```

You can then parse the response for the commit's timestamp.

More information: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit