# View remote commit without cloning repo

Tags: git

Is there any way I see contents of a commit in a remote repository without cloning it. Precisely, I am looking for a command which can work similar to `git show [refs] <commit ID>` (which is not a valid command) which will show the commit `<commit ID>` at remote repository at `ref`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41454767/query-last-commit-to-a-git-repo-without-cloning) is close to what I want, but cloning is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Have you read this answer?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13944180/4226541

Comment: What does “contents of a commit” mean exactly?

Comment: It depends on the hosting server. Some may provide APIs that allow you to retrieve data without cloning the repository. If you have access to the server, you could write a web service, for example with `Django`.

Comment: @matt I meant details like author name, email ID, date of commit etc. Similar to `git show`

Answer (score 0):

That do you want to do is not possible. My recommendation is if your repository is in Github you can explore the historical of commits in the web Github UI. In another case if you don't have a web UI for your repository the only solution that I can give you right now is clone the repository.